# Who decided the usage of the HTTP verbs on the REST architecture

Tags: rest

I've been reading [Roy Fielding dissertation](https://roy.gbiv.com/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf), but he never defined the specific usage of the HTTP methods! who suggested to use the http verbs in the specific way we use them today in REST architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> he never defined the specific usage of the HTTP methods

That's right - Fielding's thesis doesn't define HTTP.  It defines the motivation for the architectural constraints that guided the development of the definition of HTTP.

Put another way: the REST architectural style isn't limited to HTTP; you could use those same ideas to build something else.  Of course, because HTTP is here today, and inertia is a thing, you'd need to build something a LOT better than HTTP to get everybody to adopt it.

> who suggested to use the http verbs in the specific way we use them today in REST architecture?

The earliest work was, as far as I can tell, the brain child of Tim Berners-Lee in 1991.  He outlined some of that [history](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html).

After that, you should really be looking to the authors of the different standards

- [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-15)
- [RFC 2068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-18)
- [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-18)
- etc

For methods defined outside of the HTTP document set, you can look in the [IANA method registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) for the reference, and track down the authors from there.

- GET
- HEAD
- POST
- PUT
- DELETE

are all described with RFC 1945, so credit would go to those authors, and also presumably the other members of the [working group](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/) prior to May of 1996.